# Redirection in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, redirection

I have a link in my Magento 1 site

> http://beautyshop.com/index.php/hair-care.html

If I click on it,it redirects to

> http://beautyshop.com

But if I take a new tab in browser and paste the URL

> http://beautyshop.com/index.php/hair-care.html

then it is working perfectly.

My configuration in Admin Panel is `configuration>web> Search Engines Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites > Yes`

How can I solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but the issue seems:

**First time** some condition is there that returning false & redirecting to the home page. (may be some cookie is not set like that rule.)

**Second time** that condition is returning true & its loading the correct URL.

If its so then you need to find that condition location.

Comment: Thanks @Akhil Gupta. Actually I tried several ways. I tried to change .htacess file. I tried to change My configuration in Admin Panel is configuration>web> Search Engines Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites > Yes. Even I tried to edit .phtml file. I think there is some redirection set previously.